# Need to send https GET request with oauth

Tags: java, oauth

I'm new to OAuth and trying to send a https GET request to retrieve something. Earlier I was using POSTMAN to test that and I was able to execute the GET request with OAUth 1.0 header authorization. The header authorization looks something as

```
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" ,oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1" ,oauth_timestamp="1409861973" ,oauth_nonce="x1409861973681" ,oauth_version="1.0" ,oauth_signature="M+Dq62XboEd3+t6VDIcLy86zlQg="
```

The query looks something as

```
https://secure.api.abc.net/DataService/data/ServiceAccount?schema=1.0&form=json&byBillingAccountId={EQUALS,yyyyy}
```

Note that I'm able to execute this fine from POSTMAN.

Now, I need to code that in java and I'm able to generate the oauth signature fine, but I'm wondering how do I set the authorization header after that in a https request???

Please advise as I'm new to oauth and want to learn.

Answer (score 0):

I guess if your doing in Java, you will need to use the Apache HttpClient or something similar to make that request to the server and set the OAuth header to the request. 

Code sample using the Apache HttpClient below.

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

// add request header
request.addHeader("OAuth", oauthHeaderString);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```